# How do I style the content in a child element?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have:

```
<x-dialog><p>Whatever</p></x-dialog>
```

The `<p>Whatever</p>` stuff is of course passed into the x-dialog element's `<content></content>` tags:

```
<polymer-element name="x-dialog">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dialog.css">
    <core-overlay id="overlay" layered backdrop opened="{{opened}}" autoCloseDisabled="{{autoCloseDisabled}}"  transition="core-transition-center">
      <content></content>
    </core-overlay>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="dialog.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

How and where do I style my `<p>`, i.e. the content passed to my element? Note that this content is itself in a child element, core-overlay in this case, but I don't think that made a difference (it was the same result when I moved it out of core-overlay).

The style guide at http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html didn't get me to a solution (I'm assuming Dart is up to par w/ this JS guide).

Comment: Do you want to add the style to the x-dialog element or on the html page.

Comment: did you try x-foo::shadow p{background-color:red} on the main html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add the style rules to your `x-dialog` element the related section in the styling guide are [Styling distributed nodes](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html#style-distributed)

add this to your `dialog.css`

```css
content::content p {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Otherwise you can style it like any child element of normal DOM elements

```css
x-dialog p {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: x-dialog p will not work directly on html because p is inside a shadow so instead of x-dialog p it should be replaced with x-foo::shadow p{}

Comment: How did you get the info that `<p>` is in side a shadow? IMHO it could be but it can't be concluded from the info presented in the question. `<content>` allows you do put children inside a custom tag like in `<div><p>WhatEver</p></div>`

Comment: What @GünterZöchbauer means is that even though the `<p>` is *projected* through the `<content>` tag, it isn't actually *in* the Shadow DOM. That means you can style it with `x-dialog p { ... }` as normal. See [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) for more info.